# Finding the nth level neighbours of a vertex in igraph

Tags: r, graph, igraph, nearest-neighbor, neighbours

I have a big igraph object. For a given vertex of the **directed graph**, I am interested in listing the nodes at a distance less than d from the initial node. 
For instance if I am looking for the vertices within 3 steps from V0, the function would return a data frame containing in the first column the distance to the initial vertex and the second column would contain the name of the vertex.

```
level, vertex.name
0, V0
1, V23
1, V45
...
2, V12
...
3,V730
```

I tried using the function `neighbors()` of igraph (since I can specify the mode: in/out/all) but it only lists the first level vertices. Do I have to write a recursive function which uses `neighbors()` or is there a simpler way? I am using R.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the `ego()` function. It can list nodes that are a certain distance from a given node. It would be easier to give you a more specific solution if you provide a proper [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you this is precisely what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MrFlick points out, the `ego()` function from igraph does just that.

See the documentation for more detail: http://igraph.org/r/doc/ego.html